# Service stop working when there are many apps opened

Tags: android, android-service

I am just trying Services in Android with this simple code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startService(new Intent(this, PlayerService.class));
}
```

PlayerService.java:

```
public class PlayerService extends IntentService
{
    public PlayerService()
    {
        super("PlayerService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent i)
    {
        int n=0;
        while(true)
        {
            Log.i("SERVICE", "Event n." + n++);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            { }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.i("SERVICE", "Distr Service");
    }
}
```

I have declared the Service in the manifest:

```
<service android:name="PlayerService"/>
```

When I start this app and then open many other apps, then this app stop working ( as I can see in the LogCat that stop showing me "Event n..." ). Why ?

Comment: It could be GC if you don't have enough memory

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin My smartphone has only 1GB of memory. But I have noticed that other music player apps does work even if I open 100 tabs in chrome. So the problem is in my app.

Comment: Android Chrome application is different than desktop.

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin What do you mean ? I am talking only about android apps.

Comment: If you have 100 tabs open in Chrome android app, it doesn't need 100 `Services` to run in order to keep them active. Just the current one is active. This is just an example.

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin No but it use a lot of memory.

Comment: Take a look on my anser, please.

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest, Declare Like this

```
<service
     android:name="Yourpackagename.PlayerService"
     android:enabled="true" />
```

Thanks

Comment: The default value for `enabled` is `true` by the way

Comment: Done, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Service`, not `IntentService`. According documentation, `IntentService` is stoped when operation is done. Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) for more things about `IntentService`. `Service` is used for long term running. Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: The operation is not done in my case because there is a while(true), However I will try with Service too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I must use the foreground service.